# Postgres: Coalesce single value from JSONB array of objects

Tags: postgresql

I am using a JSONB column in a subquery where I need to return a single value. Each row of the JSONB column has the following form:

```json
jsonb_column
------------

{
  'data': [
    {'type': 1, 'other':'stuff'}
    {'other':'stuff'}
    {'type': 1, 'other':'stuff'}
  ],
  'other':'stuff'
}
```

I would like to return the first non-null value of `jsonb_column -> data -> type`, which would return `1` in this example.

I have tried unnesting the array elements:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column -> 'data') ->> 'type'
```

This works, but it produces multiple `type` values. When I try to `COALESCE` to get a single value, I get an error:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column -> 'data') ->> 'type')

ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in COALESCE
  Hint: You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

I'm not sure how to implement this hint, or whether it is even useful in this case. Am I on the right track with unnesting the array elements, or is there a better way to get the first field value from an array of jsonb objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After expanding jsonb to rows, you can apply filtering (WHERE) and limitation (LIMIT) to obtain what you need.

```
select coalesce(col->>'type', 'all_fields_are_null')
from jsonb_array_elements('
    {
        "data": [
            {"type": 1, "other": "stuff"},
            {"other": "stuff"},
            {"type": 1, "other": "stuff"},
            {"type": 2, "other": "stuff"}
        ],
        "other": "stuff"
    }'::jsonb -> 'data'
) tb (col)
where col->>'type' is not null
limit 1
```

(This function returns rows) **jsonb_array_elements(jsonb)** - Expands a JSON array to a set of JSON values.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html

(This function requires arguments, not rows) **coalesce(...)** - The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

Comment: You're a lifesaver @Johnny! This is exactly right. I ended up not needing the coalesce statement since we return only one result (and I don't care if I get null values). Thanks a million!

Comment: I was looking for an option to filter null values and this address the issue

Answer (score 0):

`jsonb_array_elements()` does turn a json array into rows.  You cannot use `coalesce()` across multiple rows.

Assuming your table has an `id` column, this (substituting your table for the cte) should get what you seek.

```
with jdata as (
  select 1 as id, '{
  "data": [
    {"type": 1, "other":"stuff"},
    {"other":"stuff"},
    {"type": 1, "other":"stuff"}
  ],
  "other":"stuff"
}'::jsonb as jsonb_column
)
select distinct on (id) *, obj->>'type' as first_type
  from jdata
       cross join lateral 
         jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column->'data')
           with ordinality as j(obj, rn)
 where obj->>'type' is not null
 order by id, rn;

-[ RECORD 1 ]+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id           | 1
jsonb_column | {"data": [{"type": 1, "other": "stuff"}, {"other": "stuff"}, {"type": 1, "other": "stuff"}], "other": "stuff"}
obj          | {"type": 1, "other": "stuff"}
rn           | 1
first_type   | 1
```